# I am using react-navigation/native version 6^ but my react-navigation is version 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, bottomnavigationview

and im a beginner at coding. i folllow tutorials on youtube and other online sources. i am making an expo project that is consist of bottom tab navigator but i keep on getting an error message: **Error: Creating a navigator doesn't take an argument. Maybe you are trying to use React Navigation 4 API? See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation for the latest API and guides.**

Here is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Explore from './screens/Explore';
import Saved from './screens/Saved';
import Trips from './screens/Trips';
import Inbox from './screens/Inbox';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Explore:{
    screen:Explore
  },
  Saved:{
    screen:Saved
  },
  Trips:{
    screen:Trips
  },
  Inbox:{
    screen:Inbox
  }
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and here is my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
```

i followed the documentation page from react and i still didnt get to solve it, so please can someone help me out. Thanks

Comment: Try to update your version of `react-navigation` .

Answer (score 2):

The way you have defined your navigator isn't correct in React Navigation 6. Instead of:

```js
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Explore:{
    screen:Explore
  },
  Saved:{
    screen:Saved
  },
  Trips:{
    screen:Trips
  },
  Inbox:{
    screen:Inbox
  }
})
```

Do:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={Explore} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Saved" component={Saved} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Trips" component={Trips} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Inbox" component={Inbox} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You should always read official documentation first, then follow third-party tutorials if you have problems understanding the documentation or want more examples.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation